# Handsontable pagination saving data on all pages

Tags: pagination, save, handsontable

[image: Handsontable Pagination]

Situation:
I'm using handsontable with pagination showing monthly summarized data.

Issue.
The handsontable getData function will only return the data of the current page.

Goal:
Save the data from handsontable from all pages.  I want to save the data from handsontable because user may have made changes to the handsontable on multiple pages.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fangstar/pajjhnx4/5/  My JSFiddle of the issue.

Comment: Using pagination with handsontable become really tricky as you can't use the getData() function anymore and need to work (and keep synchronized) your view with an Array. I have a solution (maybe not the best) which is basically half of my project, but very specific as I also use custom [individual column filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39769474/individual-column-filtering-with-handsontable/39772668#39772668). Tell me if you still interested or if you managed to find a solution yourself, I don't want to take the time adapting to your JSFiddle if you already have something :)