# Handson table - Filter Row

Tags: javascript, angularjs, handsontable

I am trying to create a static filter row just below the header on my Handson Table. My current HTML table has a select2 dropdown that I use to filter data for each column. Has anyone been able to do the same for a Handson Table?
[Example Image of current HTML table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeBDf.png)

Comment: show us your codes

Comment: What do you mean by filter ? Do you try to hide non-relevant row ? Highlight the relevent one ? Can you specify what are you trying to achieve exactly ?

Comment: Sure thing. I want to add a row with inputs to filter the data (Only show filtered data/rows). Handson Table has filter options that you can access via a button click on the header. I want to display an actual filter row with the input values.

Comment: @Johan Strydom I did code something like that a few month ago [that you can find here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39772668/5898393) since I didn't want to use the Pro version (which include the filter you mentioned). The filters here are not included in the table as a header but that shouldn't be the most difficult task to do